# MIPS - Why are five bubbles inserted into this pipeline?

Tags: mips, pipeline, cpu-architecture

Example in book:
Show the forwarding paths to execute this code:

```
add $3, $4, $6
sub $5, $3, $2
lw $7, 100($5)
add $8, $7, $2
```

Pipeline diagram from book:

```
I1: IF ID EX MEM WB
I2:    IF ID EX  MEM WB
I3:       IF ID  EX  MEM WB
             NOP NOP NOP NOP NOP
I4               IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
```

Why are 5 bubbles inserted there rather than something like:

```
I1: IF ID EX MEM WB
I2:    IF ID EX  MEM WB
I3:       IF ID  EX  MEM WB
I4           IF  ID  ID  EX  MEM WB
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not five bubbles, it's a bubble inserted after the third instruction and progressed through to all the pipeline stages, hence you see a bubble at each pipeline stage.

The reason a bubble is inserted is that the forth instruction require the output from the third instruction ($7). This will only be available after the ' mem' stage of the third instruction and value of $7 is needed for the 'ex' stage of instruction 4. There for inserting a bubble between 3rd and 4th instruction, output of memory stage of instruction 3 is available for the input of 'ex' stage of instruction 4.

Comment: Why is the bubble not inserted after the IF stage of instruction 4?

Comment: Both have the same effect in timing, just a different notation. I'd also use the same notation as you, but I wouldn't do ID twice, I'd just insert the nop there.

Comment: So technically both are the same? I'm really confused because I've seen examples where they use NOP, `-`, or simply repeat the ID stage to represent stalls.

Comment: Yes. From an architectural point of view all we are saying is, we cannot do this pipeline stage in this cycle.

Comment: Thank you! One last question, do you happen to know of any pipelining examples I can read up on where the register does not allow for reading and writing to happen in the same cycle?

Comment: I think it's better to phrase this as a new question to capture a fresh audience, more chances.. and more formatting for answering as well.